# how to override backdrop opacity from react-navigation-drawer v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

the problem is when i open the drawer it makes backdrop opacity on all the screen except from the drawer.

**what I want to do :** i want to remove the backdrop opacity from the header . and show the header with opacity 1 (showing it regular style)

[image]

I adding part of my drawer I dont know if it help for the question

```
      export const DrawerNavigator = () => {
        return (
        <Drawer.Navigator drawerStyle={styles.drawerStyle} drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent 
     {...props} />}>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Main" component={MainStackScreen} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
};

      const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    drawerStyle: {
        marginTop: 82,

    borderColor: "#1d2731",
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#d9b310",
    borderBottomRightRadius: 30,
},
```